# Who is "Reported Missing" addressed to?

Tags: poetry

Anna Keown's poem "Reported Missing" is addressed to a World War One soldier by a first-person narrator who is desperately hopeful that he isn't dead. Here's the poem in full:

> My thought shall never be that you are dead:
>   Who laughed so lately in this quiet place.
>   The dear and deep-eyed humour of that face
>   Held something ever living, in Death’s stead.
>   Scornful I hear the flat things they have said
>   And all their piteous platitudes of pain.
>   I laugh! I laugh! – For you will come again –
>   This heart would never beat if you were dead.
>   The world’s adrowse in twilight hushfulness,
>   There’s purple lilac in your little room,
>   And somewhere out beyond the evening gloom
>   Small boys are culling summer watercress.
>   Of these familiar things I have no dread
>   Being so very sure you are not dead.

**What relation is the soldier to the narrator?** A son? A husband? A lover? Something else?

Answers based either on a close reading of the poem itself or on outside information, e.g. about Keown's own life and family, would both be welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have no information about Keown's life, but I can make a guess based on a close reading of the poem. I think this poem is addressed to the narrator's son.

1. **The addressee was clearly loved, and loved dearly, by the narrator.**
   This is still, however, very open-ended. There are many kinds of love, and many relationships that can involve intense feelings of the heart.

   > This heart would never beat if you were dead.
2. **The flower in the addressee's "little room."**
   Flowers could be for anyone (and I am not familiar, off hand, with any floriographic references related to purple lilacs), but I think it's telling that the room is described with a juvenile, diminutive adjective. One would not describe a lover's room so, I think, nor a husband's (and as far as I know, most married couples share a room).

   > There’s purple lilac in your little room,
3. I don't think this is as strong a proof as the one above it, but I think that the reference to **"small boys"** of whom the narrator has "no dread" refer to small boys who remind this parent of the days when her son the soldier was young.
   (Of course, this could also be a reference to happy childhood memories, or to children that a couple never had, but I thought that this interpretation is a likely one, and consistent with my analysis in #2.)

Comment: Please forgive any typographical errors. I believe this is the first time I've written a Literature answer on a phone.

Comment: Nice answer! I remember coming to the same conclusion for pretty much the same reasons when I studied this poem for English Lit GCSE :-)

Comment: Purple lilacs are generally the symbol of first love

Comment: @VicAche Hmm. That throws off my answer a little bit.  I'll do some research and consider updating my answer. Thanks for the info :-)

Comment: @Shokhet worry not, the question is not tagged "symbolism" ahah :)

Comment: @VicAche Fair point :-). Just thought it might help identify the addressee.